# error building stage: failed to get filesystem from image error in tekton pipeline

Tags: docker, openshift, pipeline, tekton

I'm working on a Tekton pipeline in a OpenShift k8s clusted, i want to build a Java application from a Dockerfile in kaniko and push to a private ECR registry.

But i'm getting a weird error in the build step:

```
 [36mINFO[0m[0051] Retrieving image manifest private.repository.com:5000/custom_jdk8_tomcat8 
[36mINFO[0m[0051] Retrieving image private.repository.com:5000/custom_jdk8_tomcat8 from registry private.repository.com:5000 
[36mINFO[0m[0051] Built cross stage deps: map[]                
[36mINFO[0m[0051] Retrieving image manifest registro.kolektor.com.ar:5000/jenkins_jdk8_tomcat8 
[36mINFO[0m[0051] Returning cached image manifest              
[36mINFO[0m[0051] Executing 0 build triggers                   
[36mINFO[0m[0051] Unpacking rootfs as cmd COPY target/WSRestDeudaR2.war  "/opt/TOMCAT/webapps/javaApp.war" requires it. 
error building image: error building stage: failed to get filesystem from image: failed to write "security.capability" attribute to "/usr/bin/ping": operation not permitted

step-write-url
2022/07/07 19:02:13 Skipping step because a previous step failed
```

**Note**
I'm working over a Dockerfile that uses images from a private repository, and i'm not able to modify the base image.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM private.repository.com:5000/custom_jdk8_tomcat8
COPY target/app.war  "/opt/TOMCAT/webapps/app.war"
COPY pipeline/script/run.sh "/run.sh"
COPY apm-agent.jar /tmp/
```

**Pipeline:**

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: Pipeline
metadata:
  name: java-pipeline
spec:
  description: | 
    This pipeline clones a git repo, then echoes the README file to the stdout.
  params:
  - name: git-repo-url
    type: string
    description: The git repo URL to clone from.
  - name: git-repo-branch
    description: The git branch where to clone from.
  - name: ecr-registry
    type: string
    description: ECR Registry URL where to push the image
  - name: ecr-repository
    type: string
    description: ECR Repository where to push the image
  - name: ecr-image-tag
    type: string
    description: Image tag
  workspaces:
  - name: git-basic-auth
    description: |
      This workspace contains basic auth configuration to be used by git-clone
  - name: aws-credentials
    description: |
      This workspace contains the aws credentials to authenticate to ECR
  - name: source-dir
    description: | 
      This workspace contains the cloned repo files, so they can be read by the
      next task.   

  tasks:
  ###############
  # GIT CLONE 
  ###############   
    - name: git-clone
      taskRef:
        name: git-clone    
      params:
        - name: url
          value: $(params.git-repo-url)
        - name: revision
          value: $(params.git-repo-branch)
      workspaces:
        - name: output
          workspace: source-dir
        - name: basic-auth
          workspace: git-basic-auth         

  ###############
  # ECR LOGIN
  ###############
    - name: ecr-login
      runAfter: ["git-clone"]
      taskRef:
        name: aws-ecr-login
      workspaces:
        - name: secrets
          workspace: aws-credentials
      params:
        - name: region
          value: us-east-1   
  ###############
  # MAVEN BUILD
  ###############
    - name: maven-build-war
      runAfter: ["ecr-login"]
      taskRef:
        name: maven-build
      workspaces:
        - name: source
          workspace: source-dir
       
        
  # ###############
  # # KANIKO BUILD
  # ###############
    - name: build-push-kaniko
      runAfter: ["maven-build-war"]
      #runAfter: ["git-clone"]
      taskRef:
        name: kaniko
      workspaces:
        - name: source
          workspace: source-dir
        - name: aws-credentials
          workspace: aws-credentials            
      params:
        - name: IMAGE
          value: "$(params.ecr-registry)/$(params.ecr-repository):$(params.ecr-image-tag)"
```

I'm getting the error at the kaniko build step.

Comment: Looks like you didn't give any SCC and capabilities for your pipeline pod.
By default, OpenShift gives restricted permission to all Pods.